# Profile Installation Failed - while registering an ios device in WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I am new to WSO2 EMM. We are evaluating EMM product.

I have followed the Getting started guide and configured the following components in order to register an iOS device with the MDM module:

1) Installed the product on linux

2) General Server Configurations

3) iOS Client Configurations

4) iOS Server Configurations:
    Configured iOS settings by creating APNS certificate, MDM certificate, and followed the steps in the iOS tab in EMM console.
    1) iOS SCEP Certificate Configurations
    2) iOS MDM Configurations
    3) iOS APNS Configurations

Now while registering a user device we are getting the following exception while installing WSO2 Profile Service(root certificate has been installed successfully):

```
[2015-12-07 12:05:41,148] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.iosemm:js} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.exception.EMMException: IO exception www.apple.com (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#74)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c23._c_anonymous_6(/emm/modules/iosemm.js:74)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c23.call(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6._c_script_0(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag:7)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.call(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.call(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.exec(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.exception.EMMException: IO exception www.apple.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.plist.PlistExtractor.getDocumentElement(PlistExtractor.java:310)
    at org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.plist.PlistExtractor.extractDeviceProperties(PlistExtractor.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.util.CommonUtil.getDeviceUDIDFromProfile(CommonUtil.java:94)
    at org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.util.CommonUtil.copyInputStream(CommonUtil.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService.copyInputStream(iOSMobilityManagerService.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 85 more

[2015-12-07 12:05:41,151] ERROR {JAGGERY.ios_utils.profile:jag} -  Invalid signed data
[2015-12-07 12:05:41,152] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag#16)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag#16)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag#16)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:167)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructInternal(NativeJavaClass.java:266)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructSpecific(NativeJavaClass.java:205)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.construct(NativeJavaClass.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2349)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6._c_script_0(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag:16)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.call(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.call(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c6.exec(/emm/ios_utils/profile.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:159)
    ... 84 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is 1.1.0. If you doing it from scratch go for EMM 2.0 version. Entire documentation is available in site.

Comment: Hai can you send me the ios feature deployer file.wso2 ftp location doesn't contain that file